# android onPreviewFrame data change per 5 call on my device

Tags: android

My device is Exynos4412 android 5.0.2,
onPreviewFrame calls 30 fps, but the data only change every 5 frame.
Anyone get this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) What is your program?

Comment: My program is some code copied from internet, not special.

Comment: This is a programmers forum. We usually find bugs looking at program code. As we can't see any here, it might be very hard for this question.

Comment: @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
m_camera = Camera.open();